# Easy way to add attribute to *all* InputText elements in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to add `class="text"` to all the `TextInput` widgets. I know I can add

```
    widgets = {
        'myfield': TextInput(attrs={'class':'text'})
    }
```

For every single field, in every single form... but there's got to be an easier way? A lot of my forms are based on ModelForms, so it sets the field and widget automatically for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do that by subclassing ModelForm with a class that overrides the `__init__` method with one that calls super `__init__` and then goes over the created object's attributes, and if they are instances of `TextInput`, adds the attribute. You can probably figure out the specific mechanisms for the solution.

That's what I would explore.

Comment: Ok, but what about forms that *aren't* based on ModelForms? Would like it to work for regular forms too.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the best or cleanest solution, but what about using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text],input[type=password]').addClass('text');
});
```

I am assuming that the goal of this is styling text input, as IE6 won't understand CSS attributes

Answer (score 0):

This is a Django based solution, the already mentioned. You could create an app "MyForms" and have a forms module there:

```
# myforms/forms.py

from django import forms

class Form(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
      # Turn all CharField widgets to TextInput(attrs={'class'='text'})

class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Same as above
```

Then in your code, just do this:

```
from myforms import forms
```

instead of

```
from django import forms
```